# ¿cual es mejor printf o cout?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

siempre me negué a usar printf o printf_s por lo difícil que son usar tantos símbolos, pero lo que veo es que a bajo nivel, cout llama a demasiadas subfunciones para hacer lo mismo
Yo se que con las pc de hoy la diferencia serian a lo sumo milésimas de segundos.
La pregunta que deseo hacer es ¿es mejor printf a cout para ahorrar código y tiempo a bajo nivel ?

Comment: "milésimas de segundo" ... no subestimes el poder de un pc normalito de hoy en día. La diferencia serían como muchísimo del orden de nano o micro en todo caso! Un pc puede hacer muchas muchas cosas en unos milisegundos.

Comment: No sé qué tal se tome esta pregunta en este sitio, pero en inglés hay 2 con respuestas https://stackoverflow.com/q/2872543/13419694 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61854477/c-printf-vs-cout-performance

Comment: En la práctica muchas veces se trabaja con C++ por su performance en desmedro de la simpleza de otros lenguajes. Por lo que tu pregunta me parece relevante e interesante, espero alguien la pueda responder

Answer (score 9):

Ten en cuenta que `printf` pertenece al estándar de [c](/questions/tagged/c), si estás programando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) debes usar `std::cout`.

Pero entiendo tus preocupaciones sobre el rendimiento de `std::cout`, no eres la única persona que las tiene y hay extensa documentación sobre como mejorar ese rendimiento, por ejemplo:

- Evita usar `std::endl` ya que provoca una operación de [`flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) que en la mayoría de casos no es necesaria. En su lugar usa un `'\n'` embebido en la cadena que quieres mostrar por consola.
- No sincronices con los flujos de C, para ello llama [`std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).
- Reduce las cantidades de llamadas a `std::cout`, en lugar de esto:

  ```
  std::cout << "Hola\n";
  std::cout << "don\n";
  std::cout << "Pepito\n";
  std::cout << "Hola\n";
  std::cout << "don\n";
  std::cout << "Jose\n";
  ```

  Haz esto:

  ```
  std::cout << "Hola\n"
             << "don\n"
             << "Pepito\n"
             << "Hola\n"
             << "don\n"
             << "Jose\n";
  ```

  O aún mejor:

  ```
  std::cout << "Hola\n"
                "don\n"
                "Pepito\n"
                "Hola\n"
                "don\n"
                "Jose\n";
  ```

Ten también en cuenta que existen alternativas modernas al uso de `std::cout` que ofrecen la flexibilidad y seguridad de tipos de `std::cout` junto a la comodidad de `printf`, te presento [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) del estándar [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23):

```
// Imprime 'Esto es C++23'
std::print("{0} {3} {2}{1}!\n", "Esto", 23, "C++", "es");
```

Comment: También se puede desactivar el flush automático con [`nounitbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf)